# How can I store the same data in two different mySQL tables?

Tags: php, sql

When a new client is buying a product I want to store the client details in the `clients` table and also store the appropriate client_ID in the `orders` table.

orders table:

```
order_ID   product   client   
============================
 1501      bag         1
 1502      shoe        2
```

clients table:

```
client_ID   name      
=================
   1       Frank         
   2       John
```

I found a solution, which is working, but I have the feeling, it is not the smartest solution.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO clients(name) VALUES(?)";
$q = $con->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($name));

$sql = "INSERT INTO orders(product) VALUES(?)";
$q = $con->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($product));

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM clients ORDER BY client_ID DESC LIMIT 0, 1';
foreach ($con->query($sql) as $row) {
    $client = $row['client'];
    $sql = "UPDATE orders SET client = '$client' WHERE client IS NULL";
    $query = $con->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();
}
```

My question is, is there a better way to do this? 
(Remark: client_ID is AUTO_INCREMENT)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get the last id inserted into the database:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO clients(name) VALUES(?)";
$q = $con->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($name)); 

// Assuming you use PDO:
$clientId = $con->lastInsertId();

// For mysqli this would be:
// $clientId = $con->insert_id;


$sql = "INSERT INTO orders(product, client) VALUES(?, ?)";
$q = $con->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($product, $clientID));
```